# Não estou coneguindo exibir em tela o conteudo do Github, segundo que o exercicio pede, alguem me ajuda?

Tags: javascript, github, axios, xmlhttprequest

/*Crie uma tela com um  que deve receber o nome de um usuário no Github. Após digitar o
nome do usuário e clicar no botão buscar a aplicação deve buscar pela API do Github (conforme
URL abaixo) os dados de repositórios do usuário e mostrá-los em tela:
URL de exemplo: https://api.github.com/users/diego3g/repos
Basta alterar "diego3g" pelo nome do usuário.

Adicionar
Depois de preencher o input e adicionar, a seguinte lista deve aparecer abaixo:

- repo1
- repo2
- repo3
- repo4
- repo5

*/

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Curso Java Script</title>
```

```
<div id="app">

    <input type = "text" name = "user"/>
    <button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="exercicio2.js"></script>
```

var recebeInput = document.querySelector('#app input');
var recebeBotao = document.querySelector('#app button');
var recebeUl = document.querySelector('#app ul');

function preenchimento(preenchimento){

```
var login2 = recebeInput.value;

for(repositorio of preenchimento){

    var elementoT = document.createTextNode(repositorio.login2);
    elementoL = document.createElement('li');

    elementoL.appendChild(elementoT);
    recebeUl.appendChild(elementoL);
}
```

}

function armazenandoSite(login){

```
if(!login) return;

axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + login + '/repos')
.then(function(response){

    preenchimento(response.data);
})
.catch(function(error){

    console.log('Deu erro');
})
```

}

function adicionar(){

```
var login = recebeInput.value;
console.log(login);

var requisicao = new XMLHttpRequest();
requisicao.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/' + login + '/repos');
requisicao.send(null);

requisicao.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(requisicao.readyState === 4){

        if(requisicao.status === 200){

            armazenandoSite(login);

            }

        else{

            console.log('Algo deu errado');

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Aonde esta aparecendo alguma mensagem de erro? Qual é a mensagem?

Comment: Erro assim não tem acho que é erro de lógica porque ele não esta puxando os dados para ser printado na tela.

Answer (score 0):

O teu problema é que a tag `<script>` não está fechada. Tens de ter `<script></script>`. Para além disso podes simplificar o código e fazer algo assim:

```js
var userInput = document.querySelector('#app input[name="user"]');
var ul = document.querySelector('#app ul');

function preenchimento(dados) {
  for (repositorio of dados) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = repositorio.description;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

function adicionar() {
  const user = userInput.value;
  const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + user + '/repos';
  axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => preenchimento(response.data))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Deu erro a buscar', url);
      console.log('Erro:', error);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="user" />
  <button onclick="adicionar()" type="button">Adicionar</button>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas estão fechadas:

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="exercicio2.js"></script>

Ou não posso declrar 2 scripts assim? É porque a maior parte do código esta em outro arquivo um .js

Comment: Ficou bem mais simplificado mesmo.

Comment: E deu certo mesmo, testando aqui, mas eu deixei o script do jeito que está mesmo, e ajeitei o que foi diferente, mas eu pensei que puxava todas as informações do arquivo mais ja está bom, valeu, agora vou para o proximo desafio usando essa base.